# What is the idiom that is often said to mean 'don't be meek'?

Tags: idiom-requests

There is an idiom that says basically,

> "Better to go out in a blaze, than burn out like candle."

I'm probably totally off, but it's something like that. The point of the cliche is not to let your objection or opposition die with you, but to make it the cause of your departure.

Comment: It's better to be devoured by a lion than nibbled by ducks. But I don't know if that's close enough or if you're wanting a fire reference.

Comment: "Better to burn out than rust out", attributed to (Irish missionary to India) Amy Carmichael.

Comment: why so many downvotes on this very simple question?

Comment: Not my downvote, but shouldn't you want thousands of them, not a paltry 2?  :-)

Comment: Fortune favors the bold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be no such idiom, but instead a quote from Jack London.

- [I would rather be ashes than dust!](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/2851-i-would-rather-be-ashes-than-dust-i-would-rather)

> I would rather that my spark should burn out in a brilliant blaze than it should be stifled by dry-rot.
> "I would rather be a superb meteor, every atom of me in magnificent glow, than a sleepy and permanent planet.
> The function of man is to live, not to exist.
> I shall not waste my days trying to prolong them.
> I shall use my time.”
> ― Jack London

It is explained further  as a quote from one of Neil Young's songs ([Hey Hey, My My](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=hey+hey+My+My%2Clyrics)).

> - [It is better to burn out than fade away](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/better-burn-out-than-fade-away-kishore-shintr%C3%A9)
>   "It is better to burn out than to fade away". It's a reference to a candle or a fire. Burning out is a metaphor for living an exciting, ambitious life; one where you expend all of your energy early on, possibly even dying young like many rock stars. Fading away would be to simply live safely, not take any risks, etc. Basically living a long but boring life that doesn't impact anyone else. This quote has a similar sentiment to the Dylan Thomas' poem, which says, “Do not go gentle into that good night/but rage, Rage!, at the dying of the light.”

Comment: @EvanCarroll I am not so sure about that;  "an expression **in the usage of a language** that is peculiar to itself…" ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idiom)), "An idiom is a phrase that is **common to a certain population**" ([Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/list/7-everyday-english-idioms-and-where-they-come-from)). I don't think that the few readers of Jack London that will remember his words and the few fans of Neal Young that will remember his analogy can constitute a **usage** or **a population** in the sense that lexicographers would have it.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: "live life to the fullest" is more common/idiomatic. Some aphorisms are quoted in [30 Ways to Live Life to the Fullest](https://tinybuddha.com/blog/30-ways-to-live-life-to-the-fullest/) : I like the last one, i.e. "Follow your hopes and not your fears".

Comment: The Neil Young quote has had a lot of cultural currency, infamously being [mentioned in Kurt Cobain's suicide note](https://www.nme.com/news/music/neil-young-68-1258313) as well as in the movie Highlander.

Comment: The singer's name should be "Neil", not "Neal"; although "Neal" is a name (variant), it is apparently an error to use it for the singer (only rare cases, for instance [here](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g186338-i17-k12715175-Neal_Young_and_Dylan-London_England.html)).